# Is there a way to Deep Copy Winforms controls?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

I try to deep copy ToolStripMenuItems to add the copies to different other ToolStripMenu's.

When I try to Serialize the ToolStripMenuItem it returns Nothing (4th line in code below) and fails to make a new instance of that ToolStripMenuItem.

```
Public Module Extensions
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function DeepCopy(Of T)(ByVal Obj As T) As T
        If Obj.GetType().IsSerializable = False Then Return Nothing

        Using MStream As New MemoryStream
            Dim Formatter As New BinaryFormatter
            Formatter.Serialize(MStream, Obj)
            MStream.Position = 0
            Return DirectCast(Formatter.Deserialize(MStream), T)
        End Using
    End Function
End Module
```

My copy

```
Dim tsmiCopy As ToolStripMenuItem = tsmiOriginal.DeepCopy()
```

Comment: It's this line: `If Obj.GetType().IsSerializable = False Then Return Nothing` that returns `Nothing`. If you were to remove that line you would get an exception stating that the component is not serializable.

Comment: Look at the code for your designer.cs file. Just copy those code and put them in a method and call that method when you need a clone copy of your toolstrip, see @SuperPeanut answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Winform Control is Serializable, for the reason they all carry a handle to the active Window, which is by definition not compatible with a Serialization.

So you have to find another way around. My suggestion would be to create a function that build a brand new MenuItems, and you call it whenever you need it on a form.

To do that, you create your menu in the Designer, then open the file "MyForm.Designer.vb" and copy the part where it creates the menu, then you put that in a function.

Answer (score 1):

Proper serialization requires knowledge of the internals (private members), so that state can be restored, so can only truly be done by a given type itself. Therefore if a given type is not serializable, you will need to solve the wider problem in a different way, or work around the issue (perhaps by doing a `MemberwiseClone`) which might break your definition of a deep clone

Answer (score 1):

I did it based on this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1111658/Fast-Deep-Copy-of-Objects-by-Expression-Trees-Csha?msg=5277674

Please notice:
When creating a clone of a WinForms control the parent-child connection will be broken (the parent control does not know about the cloned object). You will have to insert the new control using

```
 target.AddControl(clone)
```

to make sure this connection is recreated and the cloned control shows up